# Symfony 2: Usage of LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Tags: api, symfony, security, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm trying to use the bundle LexikJWTAuthenthicationBundle to create a secure API but I don't really manage to use this bundle. In fact, I did the configuration like told in their GitHub project and I also created an ApiBundle but I don't understand how to login with the url /api/login.

Can you help me or give me the link to a tutorial ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to read more about [Json Web Token Authentication](http://jwt.io/introduction/).

When you are correctly understanding the principles and differences with other kinds of authentication you know, look at this good example:

[slashfan/LexikJWTAuthenticationSandbox](https://github.com/slashfan/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox)

It provides a working configuration of the bundle for an API and an AngularJS application that consumes the API by authenticating users.

You should follow the README closely, try the example, and analyse the javascript code.

The process is really easy to understand :

Assuming you have some users registered in your database, the user will make a request to your login route.
The request contains the user credentials (commonly username/password), like you could do it in a form-based authentication when the user submit its login form.

The API has a firewall that handles the login route automatically.
(The firewall is provided by the bundle documentation at the configuration part)

When the firewall intercepts the request, an event is fired and the authentication is handled by LexikJWT.

If credentials are corresponding to a valid user, A JWToken is created and added to the Response.
Otherwise, the response looks like `Bad Credentials` with a `401 Unauthorized` status.

Then, you have to use the token by adding an `Authorization: Bearer {token}` to the next requests. And same for all requests corresponding to a resource that requires to be authenticated (protected by your security configuration).

I hope it's more clear for you and you can use this powerful bundle and authentication protocol.

Answer (score 0):

@theflow I think you misunderstood something:

Here is the firewall config (`config/packages/security.yaml`) that was mentioned in [the document](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/v2.6.2/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration)

```
security:
# ...

firewalls:

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
```

and the route (`config/routes.yaml`):

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

Notice that

```
pattern:  ^/api/login
```

is not a route (to login), it just the key for to find the match routes (eg: `/api/login_check`, `/api/login/status` are matched routes) that will be handled by this firewall.

The real route for logging in is defined by

```
check_path: /api/login_check
```

here you can input the path or just the route name:

```
pattern:  api_login_check
```

So, if you want to log in by using the path `/api/login`, you must change the route definition (`config/routes.yaml`):

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login
```

and the firewall config:

```
security:
# ...

firewalls:

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        ...
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login (or api_login_check)
```